# Align the texts center with the given position

Tags: java, android

I need to draw a text using

canvas.drawText("1",x,y, paint);

But the problem is that the "text's center" doesn't match with the position I have given,Is there any way I can do the latter.I have done quite a lot of search on the topic,culdn't find any answer.Please help.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to set the alignment on your paint instance:

```
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

prior to drawing.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextAlign(android.graphics.Paint.Align)

**Edit:**
Per your indication that you'd also like it centered vertically, I'd go with an approach similar to this:

```
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);

            String text = "Hello";
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            float x = 100, y = 100;
            paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds); // Measure the text
            canvas.drawLine(0, y, canvas.getWidth(), y, paint); // Included to show vertical alignment
            canvas.drawLine(x, 0, x, canvas.getHeight(), paint); // Included to show horizsontal alignment

            canvas.drawText(text, x - bounds.width() * 0.5f, y + bounds.height() * 0.5f, paint); // Draw the text
```

or, using the center align on the paint:

```
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

            String text = "Hello";
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            float x = 100, y = 100;
            paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds); // Measure the text
            canvas.drawLine(0, y, canvas.getWidth(), y, paint); // Included to show vertical alignment
            canvas.drawLine(x, 0, x, canvas.getHeight(), paint); // Included to show horizsontal alignment

            canvas.drawText(text, x, y + bounds.height() * 0.5f, paint); // Draw the text
```

Comment: Sorry,that doesn't help....I want the Text's center to be aligned with the position I give.. (Example... if I give '1' then the 1s vertical line's center should coincide with the position that I give...

Comment: I've edited my answer to show a way to align both horizontally and vertically by measuring the text then applying offsets. I've changed it to align left, but you could still use align center and use your x value directly, but it works the same either way.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.